# Meaning of the word 'content' in particular context

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the video course on algorithms lecturer quoting following lines from the book 'The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms':

> Perhaps the most 
>   important principle of all, for the good 
>   algorithm designer is to refuse to be 
>   **content**

What does the word 'content' means in that context? Does it means 'satisfied'?

Comment: Yes, that's mostly correct. But "not demanding more than what he's acchieved" would be a better translation.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! This question of yours is easily answered with a dictionary. You might reconsider the question you ask, making it more 'complicated'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here **content** means "satisfied or pleased with the situation" and "(one who) does not expect any improvement".
Particularly here it means, a good algorithm designer must not be satisfied  with any algorithm because there are always chances for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps the most important principle of all, for the good algorithm designer is to refuse to be **content**

Your guess is right. Let's imagine this sentence:

> This algorithm designer is **content**. (predicative adjective as [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement))

The word **content** here is most likely an adjective, not a noun. The meaning differs quite a bit from

> This algorithm designer is **a student**.

The second half of the construction "noun phrase **is** noun phrase" is what is called a *[subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement)*. The nominal subject complement is used to rename the first half:

> This lake is a tranquil pool.

I have tried to imagine a situation in which we could see **content** as a noun renaming "algorithm designer", and could not come up with realistic examples.

Maybe a native speaker could come up with a situation in which it will be okay to say "This designer is content (noun)".